Flutter : Test a function did call another function or not
I have a cubit that controls three forms, and I hope to ensure that all three forms have been validated when I submit.
class MyCubit extends Cubit<MyState> {
  MyCubit()
      : super(
          const MyState(),
        );

  bool get isFormValid =>
      validateUserId(state.userId.value) &
      validatePassword(state.password.value);

  bool validateUserId(String newValue) {
    final field = UserId.validate(newValue);
    emit(state.copyWith(userId: field));

    return state.userId.isValid;
  }

  bool validatePassword(String newValue) {
    final field = Password.validate(newValue);
    emit(state.copyWith(password: field));

    return state.password.isValid;
  }

  void onSubmitted() async {
    if (!isFormValid) {
      return;
    }else{
      //go next page
    }
  }
}


I hope that when I change "&" to "&&", any errors can be detected.
Here is my unit test code
    test('isFormValid calls validate all field', () async {
      final myCubit = MyCubit();

      // Call isFormValid
      myCubit.isFormValid;

      // Verify that validate was called
      verify(myCubit.validateUserId(''));
    });

I know a verify should use a mocked object, but when I mock the cubit with "GenerateNiceMocks"
isFormValid seem to be mocked too. It will not run any validation anymore.
@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<MyCubit>()])
I'm new to unit testing, so maybe I'm approaching this all wrong.
